# Authentication to Google app script site should not be required

Tags: authentication, google-apps-script

I made a site and set "Execute the app as" to "Me" and "Who has access to the app" to "Anyone, even anonymous" but it still requires authentication sometimes. I don't want it to ever require authentication. How can I fix that?

I'm testing this with Google Chrome in Incognito mode and Safari on an iPhone.
It is forwarded by Godaddy with a 302.

The problem occurs when I pass a parameter in the url. The only effect of that is to have the page scroll to a certain position and show the appropriate hidden content using this code which really has nothing to do with authentication to Google:

```
  if(e.parameter.objection) {
    var id = e.parameter.objection;
    s +=     '<script type="text/javascript">'
      +      'goTo(' + id + ');'
      +      '</script>';
    }
```

Try the following links by right-clicking them and choosing "Open Link in Incognito Mode"

Requires authentication:

- [www.bernierebuttals.org?objection=85](http:///www.bernierebuttals.org?objection=85)
- [www.bernierebuttals.org/?objection=85](http:///www.bernierebuttals.org?objection=85)

Does not require authentication:

- http://bernierebuttals.org
- [www.bernierebuttals.org](http:///www.bernierebuttals.org)
- https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxXNKxLpyh_9H6Xo1-qzSxkVMtmBaAni4L7TrDAiU7xvLRHQ-W7/exec
- https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxXNKxLpyh_9H6Xo1-qzSxkVMtmBaAni4L7TrDAiU7xvLRHQ-W7/exec?objection=85

UPDATE:  I just discovered that the behavior has changed since I asked this question. Now when you redirect and pass in a parameter, rather than requiring you to authenticate, the page just doesn't work at all and gives you the error [image: Google Error screen]

Comment: I just talked to GoDaddy support and was told that this is just the way it is. Google requires authentication if you forward AND pass a parameter. That has to be the hokeyest software technology gotcha I have ever heard of. Any guesses about the rationale behind this decision?

Comment: there are no gotchas. you have an issue unrelated with apps script authentication per se.

Comment: @ZigMandel are you testing this in Incognito mode or while logged out of Google? I had the same results on two different computers.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't require authentication for me. You may have some problem with browser cookies, etc.

it works the way it is described, no gotcha with/without parameters.

Comment: I tested this on a different computer and had the same results. You need to not just click the links but right-click them then choose "Open link in Incognito Mode" in order to test this. You could also log out of Google first. Are you doing that?

Comment: @DanCancro  I think you replied to the wrong person. I'm not having any problem

Comment: I was asking you to confirm that you had either opened the link in Chrome's Incognito mode or after logging out of Google. This is necessary to test the problem. I have tried it on two different computers and saw the problem on both of them. I also confirmed the problem when using Firefox and Safari. The problem is at Google, and it's ridiculous.

Comment: There is no problem at Google. Something is wrong wih your setup, IMHO. I've tested numerous scripts on multiple computers with multiple browsers and it works fine. And yes, i've tested it in incognito mode as well.

Comment: I live in the US. I just asked my friends in Germany, Sweden and Detroit to test this and they are all seeing the same behavior that I am seeing. Moreover, Facebook is having the same problem. When I type as a FB comment the url with and without the "objection=85" parameter, Facebook respectively appends to my comment summary information "Meet Google Drive..." and "www.bernierebuttals.org" indicating that in the former case, Google is requiring Facebook's bot to authenticate itself and in the latter, Google is granting FB's bot access to my site. I don't know why Google would do this but it is

Comment: Then I repeat, it's a problem with your setup, not Google. There is no such problem with google

Comment: The problem happens for different people (and one bot) with different computers having different setups. So it's not a matter of setup. I appreciate your intention to help me but I honestly do not understand your logic. The problem is definitely with Google.

Comment: Try this: unpublish your current webapp, save a new version of the script and then re-publish it with the same permissions as you described above. Then check.